# Can't figure out whats wrong with my program

Tags: javascript

Hey guys when i run this program it doesnt add my numbers, basically im supposed to print the salesman with the highest selling, and the most selling car.  For example, when i type 50 amount for each car at the end it prints : 050505050 rather summing it up to a 200..

```
function salesPerson(name, id, amount) {
            this.name = name;
            this.id = id;
            this.amount = amount;
        };


    //Create car array for each brand
        var Car = new Array(4);

        //Create array of salePersons
        var Person = new Array(2);

        //Every element in the array is a object type salesPerson
        for (var i = 0; i < Person.length; i++) {
            Person[i] = new salesPerson("", 0, 0);
        }

        var temp = 0;

        var m = 0;
        var a = 0;
        var p = 0;
        var b = 0;



        for(var i = 0; i < Person.length; i++){
           Person[i].name = prompt("Enter salesman name: ");
           Person[i].id = prompt("Enter salesman id: ");

           temp = prompt("Enter Mercedes-Benz amount: ");
           Person[i].amount += temp;
           m += temp;

           temp = prompt("Enter Audi amount: ");
           Person[i].amount += temp;
           a += temp;

           temp = prompt("Enter Porsche amount: ");
           Person[i].amount += temp;
           p += temp;

           temp = prompt("Enter BMW amount: ");
           Person[i].amount += temp;
           b += temp;

        }

        var max = 0;
        var name = "";

        for (var i = 0; i < Person.length; i++) {
            if (Person[i].amount > max) {
                max = Person[i].amount;
                name = Person[i].name;
            }
        }

        alert("The best salesperson of the month is " + name + ", with the sales amount of $" + max);
```

Comment: In javascript, 0 + "50" = "050", and 0 + parseInt("50") = 50

Comment: It's coming through as a string is my guess. So when you add '0' + '50' + '50' + '50' + '50' you get '050505050'

Answer (score 0):

The result of prompt is a string so + is concatenate.  A very crude fix is to just do something like:

```
temp = +prompt("Enter Mercedes-Benz amount: ");
```

where the + causes a conversion.  Note that this is very crude - it doesn't do any checking or error handling.

Comment: Why not `parseInt` on the result? He's storing it as `temp`

Comment: parseInt would work - just using "+" is a common shortcut.  ParseInt has the advantage of detecting invalid characters

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert `temp` to `number`; Use unary operator `+` or `parseInt()` for that.

```
 for(var i = 0; i < Person.length; i++){
           Person[i].name = prompt("Enter salesman name: ");
           Person[i].id = prompt("Enter salesman id: ");

           temp = +prompt("Enter Mercedes-Benz amount: ");
           Person[i].amount += temp;
           m += temp;

           temp = +prompt("Enter Audi amount: ");
           Person[i].amount += temp;
           a += temp;

           temp = +prompt("Enter Porsche amount: ");
           Person[i].amount += temp;
           p += temp;

           temp = +prompt("Enter BMW amount: ");
           Person[i].amount += temp;
           b += temp;

        }
```

**Working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/voidSO/a84pxbc9/)**

Answer (score 0):

before adding parse string as Integer.

```js
function salesPerson(name, id, amount) {
            this.name = name;
            this.id = id;
            this.amount = amount;
        };


    //Create car array for each brand
        var Car = new Array(4);

        //Create array of salePersons
        var Person = new Array(2);

        //Every element in the array is a object type salesPerson
        for (var i = 0; i < Person.length; i++) {
            Person[i] = new salesPerson("", 0, 0);
        }

        var temp = 0;

        var m = 0;
        var a = 0;
        var p = 0;
        var b = 0;



        for(var i = 0; i < Person.length; i++){
           Person[i].name = prompt("Enter salesman name: ");
           Person[i].id = prompt("Enter salesman id: ");

           temp = parseInt(prompt("Enter Mercedes-Benz amount: "));
           Person[i].amount += temp;
           m += temp;

           temp = parseInt(prompt("Enter Audi amount: "));
           Person[i].amount += temp;
           a += temp;

           temp = parseInt(prompt("Enter Porsche amount: "));
           Person[i].amount += temp;
           p += temp;

           temp = parseInt(prompt("Enter BMW amount: "));
           Person[i].amount += temp;
           b += temp;

        }

        var max = 0;
        var name = "";

        for (var i = 0; i < Person.length; i++) {
            if (Person[i].amount > max) {
                max = Person[i].amount;
                name = Person[i].name;
            }
        }

        alert("The best salesperson of the month is " + name + ", with the sales amount of $" + max);
```

Comment: I have a function called function - > isNegative(num) {
    if (num < 0) {
        alert("Try again, with a positive amount!");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
};
 and im using it to validate the amounts above, but if i type in 2 digits it ends the program there

Answer (score 0):

When you take an input from the user, it is received as a string. You need to convert this input to an int. This can be done by using `parseInt(value, radix)`. To know more about `parseInt` function see http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseInt.asp